# Date methods marked deprecated, but recommended Calendar equivalents don't do what I want

Tags: java, android

I'm working with Date objects in my code, and the documentation on many of the methods I'm using say that the method is deprecated and that I should use the Calendar object and its equivalent methods.  The easiest example to remember is `Date.getHours()` and `Date.getMinutes()` methods say to use `Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)`, etc.

But, in the case where I'm working with two dates, performing some math on them and then comparing them, they seem to be referring to the same instance on Calendar.  The documentation for Calendar says to use `Calendar.getInstance()`, but that seems to be returning a singleton Calendar instance.

The Date object was working just fine for me, but I'm afraid to use methods marked deprecated because that makes me feel like my code could break in a future version of the api.

Is it safe to use Date?  Or is there a way to fetch unique Calendar instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calendar.getInstance() does not return a singleton. The following test

```
@Test
public void testCalendar() throws InterruptedException {
  Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-hh:mm:ss.SSS");
  String s1 = df.format(cal1.getTime());
  String s2 = df.format(cal2.getTime());
  assertEquals(s1, s2);
}
```

produces

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<20111129-02:50:4[5].507> but was:<20111129-02:50:4[6].507>
```

When doing date math, you should never work on the underlying milliseconds, because then you make the assumption that every day has 24 hours and every hour has 3600 seconds. Use the Calendar methods instead, or switch to JodaTime.

Comment: I made the assumption that I'm getting a singleton object because three different Calendar objects returned from Calendar.getInstance return the same value from the hashCode method.  I know that in .Net, this means that the variables point to the exact same object.  Is that not the case in Java?  I did run subsequent tests including sleeping the thread like you did as well as modifying one Calendar that was retrieved immediately after another, and indeed all date/time values were as expected.  I'm looking into JodaTime as you recommended as well.

Comment: @Rich No no no!  If `hashCode()` returns the same value for two objects, it does *not* mean the objects are the same instance *nor* does it mean they are equal!

Comment: @Rich If the class's `hashCode()` method is implemented well, then there's a good *chance* that, if the hash codes of two objects are equal, then the objects themselves are equal.  But you can't know for certain (that's what the `equals()` method is for).

Comment: Right, the Java spec only requires that if 2 objects are equal they must have the same hashCode. But the reverse is not required, in fact the implementation int hashCode() { return 1; } is legal (although not recommended).

Comment: wow.  in .Net, you can override GetHashCode and do whatever you want, but everything that's in the base class library provided by the .Net framework returns a unique hash code for each unique instance.  Thanks for that clarification!

Comment: @Rich It's the same with Java, if I'm not mistaken.  The default implementation of `hashCode()` generates a hash code based on the object's memory address, so it will be unique for every instance of the object.  This works fine because, the default impl of `equals()` only returns true if the two references point to the exact same object.  If you override either of these methods, then you must make sure to follow the rules that wallenborn stated in his comment.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Date object and then use Calendar.setDate(Date d) to define another Calendar object. Then you can easily manipulate the two dates.

Another way of manipulating the dates would be to manipulate their long values (in millis). You can subtract, add or whatever. After that you can create a Date object from the resulting long value, and then a Calendar from the Date.

Alternatively, you can use the Joda Time APIs which are relatively easy to use.

Regards!

Comment: +1 for Joda Time. Easy to use, they do everything you may want to, including formatting and operations, and they're thread-safe (as opposed to SimpleDateFormat stuff which is the source of many concurrency problems)

Comment: Joda Time sounds like what I'm looking for.  Calendar can do it too, but the object feels like it's way more than I need.  I'm reading the JodaTime docs and running some tests now.  Is there any reason I wouldn't use it, or is it just awesome and I should have no reason to switch over to JodaTime for all my DateTime objects?

Comment: You should switch to Joda Time API. It is easy and intuitive. Also there are rumors it will be integrated into the JDK soon, but not sure if there is any truth to that. Anyway, i can highly recommend it.